# When redirect index.html to 404 error page, Apache doesn't load any page

Tags: apache, configuration-files

I have a website hosted on Apache server and on Ubuntu machine. When the visitor type mydomain.com/index.html I would like to redirect it to the custom 404 page error.
So in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` I edit the `mydomain.com.conf` file in the folling way:

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ErrorDocument 403 /custom_403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.html
    Redirect      404 /index.html
```

But now when I type `www.mydomain.com` the Apache doesn´t load neither the `index.html` nor the `custom_404.html`. Instead, it shows a folder structure with what I have in the `DocumentRoot`.

How can I achive my goal without this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to prevent users to access the website by writing `mydomain.com/index.html`. I edited the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf` and in the line where is write `DirectoryIndex` I changed `index.html` by `somethingElse.html`. Then in the `DocumentRoot` I also changed the name of `index.html` by `somethingElse.html`.
I kept the configuration of the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf` so every time the user type `mydomain.com/index.html` it gets a `404` error custom page.